# Отправка картинки через Okhttp и сохранение его в api на php

Tags: php, android, kotlin, api, okhttp

Всем привет! Пытаюсь отправить картинку на сервер через OkHttp и сохранить его на сервере. Вот кнопка которая отправляет картинку. Картинка уже в Bitmap.

```
uploadBtn.setOnClickListener{view ->
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            imageBitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
            val imageByteArray = stream.toByteArray()

            val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
                .add("code", "createOrg")
                .add("createdBy", "8")
                .add("name", editText.text.toString())
                .add("descript", editText2.text.toString())
                .build()

            val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image", "test.jpg",
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                    imageByteArray))
                .build()

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .post(formBody)
                .build()

            var client = OkHttpClient()

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object :Callback{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    runOnUiThread{
                        println("resp =  ${response.body()?.string()}")
                        //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Everything is Ok! : ${response.body()?.string().toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        finish()
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    runOnUiThread{
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SOME ERROR : ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                }

            })
        }
```

А вот код где я пытаюсь сохранить картинку на сервере.

```
$data = $_POST();

if ($data['code'] == 'createOrg') {
    $createdBy = $data['createdBy'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $desc = $data['descript'];
    $file_path = "images/";
    $file_path = "images/".basename($data['image']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($data['image']['tmp_name'], $file_path);
    
    $sql = "insert into organization(name, descript, createdBy, image) values('$name', '$desc', '$createdBy', '$file_path')";
    $res = $con ->query($sql);
    
    if ($res != false) {
        echo "1";
    } else echo "0";
    
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: $_POST же массив, а не функция

Comment: А как тогда получить и код и файл одновременно? @ВадимАлександру